# Thomas Calculus wrong question on Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

**The problem**:
An antibiotic is administered intravenously into the bloodstream at a constant rate $r$. As the drug flows through the patient's system and acts on the infection that is present, it is removed from the bloodstream at a rate proportional to the amount in the bloodstream at that time. Since the amount of the blood in the patient is constant, this means that the concentration $y=y(t)$ of the antibiotic in the bloodstream can be modeled by the differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=r-ky \text{, }k>0 \text{ and constant}
$$

- If $y(0)=y_0$, find the concentration $y(t)$ at any time $t$.
- Assume that $y_0<\frac{r}{k}$ and find $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}y(t)$. Sketch the solution curve for the concentration.

**My Answer**:
The solution to this would be
$$
\int_{y_0}^y\frac{dy}{r-ky}=\int_0^tdt
$$
which gives
$$
y(t)=\frac{r}{k}-\frac{r-ky_0}{ke^{kt}}
$$

The curve for which looks like this:
[image]

The problem here is $y(t)$ does not go to $+\infty$ for any $t>0$.

Could the question be wrong?

Comment: The concentration can't go ovr $1$ [i.e. 100%] so why expect it to be unbounded?

Comment: What is meant is $\lim_{t \to \infty}$, not $\lim_{y \to \infty}$.

Comment: @coffeemath You're right. But I know nothing about the concentration of drugs in blood an as such....

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are most probably right...